# Which actions should I modify or remove to prepare my app for the "February 2013 Breaking Changes"?

Tags: facebook, action, facebook-opengraph

We're developing an app on Facebook which uses FB Open Graph API to post into users' timelines. We use these actions:
[image: Comment, Create, Find, Follow, Love, and Try On.]

Today I received an email alert about "February 2013 Breaking Changes" (https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/#february-2013).

The problem is that I failed to figure out which actions I need to modify/remove in order to make my app compliant.

Comment: Have you read the blog post that they linked to?